# How to create a follow-up button in CSS which limits itself upto the length of the container?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Some text
    <span class="fa fa-ban"></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

where the "Some text" part can be anything. What I want to achieve is the following in CSS:
[image].

I tried using absolute positioned elements, floats, and couple of other hacks but none of them worked. Can somebody help me with how I can achieve the same? I don't even know if this is achievable with CSS but I could be wrong.

Comment: Is your HTML set in stone, or are you open to alternative elements to produce the desired result?

Comment: I'm open to alternative way of structuring HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flexbox can easily do this:

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 200px;
  border:1px solid;
}

.box span:first-child {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.box span:last-child {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css">
<p class="box">
  <span>Some text</span>
  <span class="fa fa-ban"></span>
</p>

<p class="box">
  <span>more and more text</span>
  <span class="fa fa-ban"></span>
</p>

<p class="box">
  <span>a lot of text here to have an overflow</span>
  <span class="fa fa-ban"></span>
</p>
```